# Can't install Joomla Test template

Tags: php, xml, templates, joomla

I want to make a test template for Joomla, but I can't install it. I don't know why it doesn't work.

I have the css folder, an images folder, index.php and a templateDetails.xml. So here's my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="3.8" type="template">
    <name>ts-melina</name>
    <creationDate>2018-03-19</creationDate>
    <author>Melina Gaul</author>
    <authorEmail>gaul.melina@gmail.com</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>http://www.example.com</authorUrl>
    <copyright>Melina Gaul 2018</copyright>
    <license>GNU/GPL</license>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <description>Das offizielle Design von ts-melina</description>
    <files>
        <filename>index.php</filename>
        <filename>templateDetails.xml</filename>
        <folder>images</folder>
        <folder>css</folder>
    </files>
    <positions>
        <position>header</position>
        <position>menu</position>
        <position>cover</position>
        <position>willkommen</position>
        <position>angebote</position>
        <position>socialmedia</position>
        <position>leistung-1</position>
        <position>leistung-2</position>
        <position>leistung-3</position>
        <position>siegel</position>
        <position>footer</position>
    </positions>
</extension>
```

Here's my index.php

```
<?php defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" >
<head>
<jdoc:include type="head" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/template.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<header><jdoc:include type="modules" name="header" style="xhtml" /></header>



<footer><jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" style="xhtml" /></footer>


</div><!--#wrapper-->

</body>
</html>
```

Did I write something wrong? Or do I need anything else. I make it like the tutorials or the documentation of Joomla, but I can't install it. It's very important and I need it soon.

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to install?